# Проблема с циклом JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Нужна ваша помощь. Есть задание - "Спросить у пользователя возраст. Если больше 18 заходите, если меньше - уходите. Но так же нужно предусмотреть что польозователь ничего не введет".
Написал такой код

```js
function userAge() {
 var age = prompt('Привет. Сколько вам лет?');

 if (age >= 18) {
  alert('Вы можете войти на сайт!');
 } else if (age < 18) {
  alert('Вход на сайт только для людей старше 18!');
 } 
 else {
  alert('Попробуйте еще раз!');
  age = prompt('Привет. Сколько вам лет?');
 }
}

userAge();
```

Но условие в else не возвращается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое - вам нужно сразу конвертировать строку в `int`. В `JS` это можно сделать с помощью `+`;

Далее - используем `do-while` цикл и проверяем, верное ли значение введено как `age > 0` (количество лет человека не может быть меньше нуля, младенец младше года вряд ли зайдет).

Также я предлагаю обернуть в цикл только момент ввода данных.

```js
function userAge() {
  let age;
  do {
    age = +prompt('Привет. Сколько вам лет?');
  } while (age <= 0);

  if (age >= 18) {
    alert('Вы можете войти на сайт!');
  } else if (age < 18) {
    alert('Вход на сайт только для людей старше 18!');
  }
}

userAge();
```

Answer (score 3):

проверяйте переменную age, если она пустая или не является числом запустите функцию еще раз (рекурсия).

```js
function userAge() {
  var age = prompt('Привет. Сколько вам лет?');
  
  if (age && !isNaN(age)) {
    if (age >= 18) {
      alert('Вы можете войти на сайт!');
    } else if (age < 18) {
      alert('Вход на сайт только для людей старше 18!');
    }
  } else {
    alert('Попробуйте еще раз!');
    userAge();
  }
}

userAge();
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: А если я любую строку напишу?..

Answer (score -1):

А если так? )

```
function userAge() {
    var age = prompt('Привет. Сколько вам лет?');

    if (age >= 18 && age != "") {
        alert('Вы можете войти на сайт!');
    } else if (age < 18 && age != "") {
        alert('Вход на сайт только для людей старше 18!');
    } 
    else {
          alert('Попробуйте еще раз!');
          userAge();      
         }
}

userAge();
```

Comment: Кто минусит и по какому поводу?